# Dropbox Startup problem

Tags: 14.04, dropbox

Today I installed Dropbox 2.10.30 on Ubuntu 14.04 using this commands.

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -

~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

It works perfectly but there is no dropbox icon on my dash and also i can't set dropbox as startup application

I tried `dropbox start -i` on start-up and it won't work(also not work on terminal)
then i added `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` to start-up, but no any luck.

how do i set dropbox as startup application.

PS:

Dropbox app-indicator icon works perfectly with `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have restarted multiple times after update/upgrade and now it's working properly with this `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` start-up command.